# Given the size of far and near plane, find other parameters of a frustum

Tags: camera, cocos2d, frustum

I am trying to find the correct parameters for setting up my perspective camera. But I don't know the mathematics involved in that. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

My near plane should have width 1920 and height 1080 while my far plane should have width 3840 and height 2160. Aspect ratio is 1.7

Now how do I get the appropriate fovy, near plane distance and the far plane distance so that I get the desired frustum?

Edit: The world size is 3840 x 2160, and the entire world is divided into four quadrants. The size of a quadrant is 1920 x 1080. The user can zoom out and look at all four quadrants (Eagle eye view) or zoom in and look at one quadrant at a time. The important thing is, the world size should always be twice the size of a quadrant (and the area should be four times the area of a quadrant). When the game is actually being played, I just modify the Z position of the camera to zoom-in/zoom-out. Decrease the Z position to zoom in, increase the Z position to zoom out.

Comment: Those numbers look like pixel dimensions, but the near and far planes aren't really measured in pixels. They're in the game's world coordinates, which can be in unrelated units like meters. Moreover, there's an infinite variety of frustum shapes with a given near & far size — wider ones with the planes close together, or skinny ones with the planes far apart. So we'll need another constraint to nail down a unique solution. Can you tell us about the effect you're trying to achieve by setting up the camera based on plane sizes? It might help us find what extra constraint is right for your case.

Comment: I added some more info. Will this be sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately no, unless your world is 2D, in which case you could use an orthographic camera just as easily. The zooming behaviour you're describing isn't really related to near & far planes or FoV, and you can get the same zooming behaviour with many different choices of each. Near & far control the precision and cutoff points of your depth butfer, so you'd usually set them dynamically to closely fit your scene at a given zoom, rather than leaving the bulk of the expressive range unused until you zoom in/out. FoV controls the intensity of the perspective distortion & receding of far objects.

Comment: My world is 2D, and orthographic camera isn't working because no matter the Z distance, orthographic camera draws everything on the same plane. I can't change the viewport because cocos2D doesn't support that! I am using perspective camera right now and I am getting the desired results, except that they are not accurate and when zoomed in, the quadrants are slightly misplaced (by few pixels) and when zoomed out, they zoom a few pixels more than required